# JS if...else and && not matching the values of the variables being tested

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some validation js that will pick the most specific value (a value in filter 3 is more specific than filter2, etc)

The following still is returning "null" and I'm not sure why?

```
var filter1 = ["ELEC"];
var filter2 = new Array();
var filter3 = new Array();

function getParentCode(filter1, filter2, filter3)
{
    if (filter1 === null && filter2 === null && filter3 === null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (filter1 !== null && filter2 === null && filter3 === null)
    {
        return filter1;
    }
    else if (filter1 !== null && filter2 !== null && filter3 === null)
    {
        return filter2;
    }
    else if (filter1 !== null && filter2 !== null && filter3 !== null)
    {
        return filter3;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you're calling `getParentCode`.

Comment: retVal = getParentCode(filter1,filter2,filter3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather of the params you're sending to the function, the correct code maybe something like this:

```
function getParentCode(filter1, filter2, filter3){
  if(filter3.length>0) return filter3;
  if(filter2.length>0) return filter2;
  if(filter1.length>0) return filter1;
  return null;
}
```

If you did indeed mean null, then follow Software Monkey's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
function getParentCode(filter1, filter2, filter3) {
    if      (filter3!==null) { return filter3; }
    else if (filter2!==null) { return filter2; }
    else if (filter1!==null) { return filter1; }
    else                     { return null;    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you changed the logic on purpose?

Comment: I followed his statement "filter 3 is more specific than filter 2, etc".

Comment: In his case, `filter3` would need to be returned when all 3 variables are not `null`, in yours and the other answer it works even if `filter1` and `filter2` are `null`.

Comment: @pilsetnieks: Yes, but his code and his intent as described were at odds, and the intent described made more sense to me than the code given.